# Visualforce page bringing data from custom object

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

I am new to visualforce and I would like to create the page which would display values from custom object (Staff__c). I would like it to work this way that each user would see value from  the Holidays Remaining field from his/hers record in the Staff object (Staff records have the same name like the name of user). Could anyone help me with this please?

Comment: What particular problem do you have? Map your object's fields to a columns in VF's table tag?

Comment: The main problem is that I am very new to visualforce and by now I feel slightly lost as my skills are limited. the biggest challenge is to make the relation somehow that Salesforce would recognize the user and according to this choose the record from the Staff object

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? As far as I understand you are trying to build a VF page. This VF page should contain some information from Staff__c object basing on current user. Am I right?

Comment: Yes Indeed. I would like to make the page where if John Smith enters it, it will bring only his details. If Jane Doe enters the page she will see only her details.

Answer (score 0):

Staff__c object should have a link to a User.
In your controller for VF page you pull all needed data basing on current user who opened the VF page.